# Getting iPhone touch coordinates without using javascript events?

Tags: touch, iphone

Is there any way to get iPhone coordinates without relying on javascript callback events? `touchmove` generates way too many events to be used in any kind of tight loop (like a game), and without multi-threading, the only option would seem to be non-event driven input coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's just no way to do this, although perhaps one day this will be possible.